# Altium Design Rule - How to apply to one named component?

Tags: altium, design-rules

How can I build an Altium Designer rule that applies to only one component or reference designatorrefdes?

I tried selecting my component, S1, from the Query Helper, but that just puts the string 'S1' into the query.  What else belongs there?

[image: Altium rules named component]

Comment: Can you try with `InComponent('S1')`? At the moment I cannot check any of my previous rules, but I am sure that I have used the `InComponent('U1')` syntax to create some component specific rule.

Answer (score 2):

It's InComponent(), i.e.:

```
InComponent ('J2') OR InComponent('J3') OR InComponent ('J4') OR InComponent ('J5')
```

Likewise, if you end up making a ComponentClass, it's InComponentClass():

```
InComponentClass('WaivedClearance')
```

Remember that if you do a positional re-annotation or something similar at the end that changes reference designators, your rules and component classes won't update automatically.